# Is a Microsoft MVP required to disclose affiliation?

Tags: discussion, external-links, self-promotion

Microsoft ([124,000 active employees worldwide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft)) has a system for rewarding non-employees, the "[Most Valuable Professional](https://mvp.microsoft.com/)".

With apparently [3,024 active MVP worldwide](https://mvp.microsoft.com/en-us/MvpSearch?kw=&x=16&y=12), that's very few people compared to how many devs Microsoft [loves](https://www.computerworld.com/article/2848877/microsoft-nobody-loves-developers-more-than-us.html)[.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I14b-C67EXY)

I'd like to know if MVP people, who are kind of **non-employees evangelists**, are required to disclose that they are MVP when linking to Microsoft blogs and products in their answers?

(I believe the answer is "no", but I would like a confirmation if possible)

Comment: I know we're at least strongly encouraged to do so. I don't know if there's a requirement either. I've had at least [one instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35184048/what-is-after-internet-explorer-11-on-windows-7-how-well-will-es2016-be-support#comment82605261_35184087) of someone being unsure if I was a speaking on Microsoft's behalf, so there are valid concerns behind asking this question.

Comment: (FYI, because we're not employed by Microsoft, MVPs are *not* affiliated with it - our disclosure would therefore indicate *non*-affiliation. That said, some of us like myself have internal contacts, and our feedback and complaints tend to get taken more seriously than others' - that's as far as any potential conflicts of interest go.)

Comment: Actually, most of the MVPs I know would strongly diagree that they were "evangelists". MS Marketing folks would sure like that... Granted, I'm from the old school, but historically, MVPs have strongly resisted any attempt to rope them into that role. The award is made for supporting those who use Microsoft products, based on in-depth knowledge in a technology. So it makes sense that someone who has achieved the award will answer questions associated with that technology. And of course in order to solve such issues it's necessary sometimes to point people to documentation, etc. on the MS site.

Comment: I've never felt the need to disclose although my profile page readily identifies me as such and it is a moniker I carry with pride. On the flip side, I'm beholden to many NDA's that restrict me from letting you in on some things that I'm privy to.

Comment: ... and just for the record, not all MVP's that have drank that special Kool-aid agree with MS 100% of the time.

Comment: @Jeeped I'm not a native English speaker, and with your 85,119 reputation you should know there is an EDIT button somewhere. ☻☺

Comment: @Cœur - Sorry if you took offence. It was intended as tongue-in-cheek 'humor' and something got lost in translation. [edit] forgot a smilie face :)

Comment: @Jeeped Is that some kind of [Electric Kool-Aid Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Electric_Kool-Aid_Acid_Test) you have to take?

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook - While I'm not a stranger to a pitcher of electric kool-aid, I think the pop culture reference to 'drinking the kool-aid' is more of an interference to a cult worship ideal. Again, tongue-firmly-implanted-in-cheek. [edit] oops! forgot the smilie thing again! :)

Comment: I don't understand where this question is coming from. Even users who are employed by Microsoft (or any company) are not required to "disclose" it, why would MVPs? Many Stack Overflow users work in companies that offer development-related services - this only becomes a problem if they are pushing their products too hard **on unrelated questions**.

Comment: @Kobi, good comment! Regarding in which circumstances to disclose, I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion

Comment: @Cœur - fwiw, when I was involved with the evolution that turned out to be [answers.microsoft.com](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/profile/a05bdd23-6c19-4f50-9b4a-3c6ae7d72590), they pinned an `MVP` badge to me that followed me around the site. If SO decides I need one, I'll happily wear it. A badge is better than a hat any day in my book.

Comment: Just to provide a point of view -- A MVP award is usually given retroactively for one's community contribution in the *prior* year. One becomes MVP because one wants to contribute something to the community, which is usually diametrically opposed to a marketeer (I refuse to use the "e" word) which has to be forward-looking. One becomes MVP because they are *independent* which also implies they are not obliged to toe Microsoft's party line. Oh, also, one cannot be both a MVP and Microsoft's employee. If MVPs are still "affiliated" even so, then I don't know what affiliation is.

Comment: *To be fair* the sneaks over at Ubuntu, Apache, GNU and pals have been rewarding their non-employee evangelists by giving them free, superior software. Keep your eye on them.

Answer (score 85):

Stack Overflow isn't built for recommendations or architecture designs. You shouldn't see too many questions that look like "What tool X by company Y can I use to build Z" (in fact, most of these would be explicitly offtopic!).

Questions on SO are supposed to be specific usecases - "my code is supposed to do X but I get Y" or "how can I do X under circumstances A, B and C". Most such questions are already tied to the specific technology you're using, so there's no place to promote other technologies. In fact, I guess most such attempts would be flagged and removed as offtopic (or even spam) anyway, regardless of whether the poster was a regular John Doe, a Microsoft MVP or Satya Nadella.

And if we do decide that Microsoft MVPs must disclose their affiliation (although I find it hard to think of someone that **wouldn't** want to disclose this on his or her profile), where do we stop?
Most large tech companies have some sort of community programs - should we single Microsoft out? What about professional certifications? Should we require people to list all the certifications they've achieved? What about open source contributions? I have a single patch merged to the Spring framework. Should I mention it every time I answer a question about Spring?

Comment: Keep in mind that a recommendation is a valid answer to many how-to style Questions, so even if the question isn't asking for recommendations, it may receive them. Also, we require disclosure of affiliation to be in the answer alongside the recommendation. Disclosing affiliation in your profile doesn't count.

Answer (score 16):

### Please don't do this.

MVP status is in my profile where it belongs. I disclose affiliation when I link to my OSS project (when relevant; usually in disposable comments), because managing the open-source project you're linking to *is* an affiliation. Being MVP isn't.

This is what MVP is:

> *We recognize and value your exceptional contributions and commitment to technical communities worldwide. By sharing your real world expertise and technical skills, you demonstrate outstanding technical community leadership. Thank you.*

That's all.

Remember when seeing an answer from a 10K+ rep user made you go "oh wow, this guy knows his stuff"? *Vote for the content, not the user*, right? I can't see myself putting a disclaimer at the bottom of every one of my [excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel)[vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba) answers that links anywhere Microsoft...and just amplifying that wrong impression that my words carry more weight or truth than anybody else's. My impostor's syndrome couldn't take it!

I like to think I earn my upvotes with the quality of my answers, not because of my rep score, and definitely not because my answers look like they're somehow endorsed by Microsoft.

There's actually a clause in the MVP legalese about how Microsoft MVP awardees aren't allowed to use the term "MVP", or the MVP logo, to make it look like Microsoft is endorsing a product or a statement: I simply wouldn't feel comfortable at all doing this.

MVP awardees speak for themselves, not for Microsoft.

When linking to an article, be it hosted by Microsoft or by WordPress or anyone else, IMO the only thing that warrants disclosure is when you authored that article - whether you're an MVP or not: MVP status makes no difference.

Answer (score 4):

Why stop at MVPs?  Why not include [GDEs](https://developers.google.com/experts/)?  Should we have people disclose if they have certain certifications from major corporations as well?  Should we require people to disclose if they're contributors to a project or employees of a company?

What is it you're trying to solve for here? Is there a problem with the system where questions or answers are getting unfairly upvoted/downvoted?

Most MVPs I've encountered are pretty vocal about their membership.  But most also tend to give good advice in their product speciality (hence their status). At the end of the day, if I'm looking for advice or assistance with SQL Server or Office or some other MS product, I don't care if it's from a MVP or a MCSE or a GDE or a PhD or whatever.  This site rewards answers that are helpful, and it does it pretty well.  Never mind that it would be pretty impractical to enforce such a requirement (especially as these statuses tend to expire or change over time, and it may be difficult to link a particular SO user to their real identity if their status is even published anywhere).

Comment: We currently _do_ require that users disclose any affiliation they may have with the provider of a service or product they are recommending. This question is asking whether being an MVP is considered affiliation or not.

Comment: So do people disclose they're CCIE if they make a Cisco related recommendation? Should it be required?